# Downloading imported SQLite database with commited data post-test execution

Tags: sqlite, jmeter, blazemeter

I have created Jmeter tests which I'm running on Blazemeter including an SQLite database. I need to obtain the updated database post tests.

The database was added to a BlazeMeter "Share Folder" and the "Read Only" option is disabled. I download the database from the Blazemeter UI but on inspection proves to be unaltered. I know it *must* be written on as the tests are successful; reading new information that was written on during test execution. What am I missing here?

[.jmx file with the JDBC logic used](https://www.file.io/i4ox/download/6CAGF0C9Dy0L). Run file in VirusTotal before opening.

Answer (score 0):

How we're supposed to help without seeing your `${TEST_PATH}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value?

So far I can only recommend checking out [Shared Folders](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002087717-Shared-Folders-Performance-Testing-) documentation chapter which says:

> **Reference Shared Folders in Your Script**
>
> To point to a file from an included Shared Folder in your script, use the "folder/filename" style path: folder1/file11.csv **(no leading slash).**

so I can only think of the situation when your `${TEST_PATH}` variable contains leading slash and the sqlite database is being created on the BlazeMeter engine directly (not in the shared folder) and it's getting lost when the engine terminates.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm still getting used to dealing with the subtle pathing issues that arise from porting JMeter scripts to Blazemeter... The JDBC logic of the file you looked at was taken from the incorrect Jmeter test; the one I run locally during development. I updated the link in the question.

Comment: It's very good that you read first line of the answer. However there are 3 more lines which explain the root cause of the problem and what needs to be done to fix it. Also be informed that [using Beanshell is some form of a performance ant-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

Comment: LOL Did you look at the JDBC connection controller of the updated file? I was using path to shared folder where the database is found... the shared folder called "db". The User Defined Variable controller serving no purpose in updated example file. Good to know about Groovey though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So! Found the answer to why my SQLite database, despite beings in a shared-folder in JMeter, was not saving/committing/writing to database. (Data generated at test execution)...

Ultimately, this feature was intentionally left out. Aside there being a glaring issue of I/O operations to the database with tests at large scale, the general idea is that the test files uploaded (shared folder or test specific) should be static data.

However! At runtime, Blazemeter essentially makes a copy of test files in a VM where runtime data gets saved and gets packaged with log files inside "artifact.zip"! If you have the need to view/collect these updated files... you will have to manually download the archived log data and do what you will with the file.